# I have been working on an Android project to track my walking. Is there any way to get accuracy less than 10 meters in all the phones

Tags: android

I have been working on an Android project to track my walking. Is there any way to get accuracy less than 10 meters in all the phones.

Different phones are returning different accuracy levels. So not sure what points I should consider to draw path. If I consider low accuracy , loosing the path, if I consider high accuracy zig zag path over buildings.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Fused Location**

With fused location you do not need to query best location provider. If you want to get high accuracy you only set it to the location request.

```
setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
```

for more about `FusedLocationApi` refer here [FusedLoactionApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi)

Comment: I'm using the same high_accuracy but different phones are giving different accuracies. Only one or 2 models giving accuracy less than 10m, all other phones are returning 15 to 25.